# How to get content from a remote feature branch to another local feature branch

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I'm new to git, and how I fell into the problem is here step-by-step :

1. I've cloned `main` branch's all content from a remote repository (let's say = `https:github.com/myrepo`) using command :

```
git clone https:github.com/myrepo
```

2. Then, I've created a feature branch `myFeature1` and checked out to it-

```
git checkout -b myFeature1
```

3. Then, I added some code in 'myFeature1' branch, staged the file, commited the code and pushed the changes using commands -

```
git add file1.txt
git commit -m "My first function"
git push origin myFeature1
```

4. Now, I want to take latest pull from remote `main` into my local 'main' branch, So I execute -

```
git checkout main
git pull
```

5. Now, I want to create a new feature branch `myFeature1Enhanced`, that should have the latest content from `main` as well well my already developed `myFeature1` branch content that I've pushed earlier.

So what commands should I execute to achieve the point 5 ?

Just a try -

```
git checkout -b myFeature1Enhanced 
git pull origin main
git pull origin myFeature1
```

Are above commands correct to achieve point number 5? Can anyone please help me / suggest on this? I don't want to lose any of my developed code.

Answer (score 0):

> Are above commands correct to achieve point number 5?

Yes. Your proposed solution should work fine. Here are some additional notes about this:

1. The command in step 5, `git pull origin main`, may be redundant as you just pulled the latest `main` in step 4. (Unless enough time has elapsed for more commits to land on the remote `main` branch that you haven't fetched yet.)
2. When you create a new branch, you can add another optional argument to specify the starting commit rather than defaulting to the commit you are currently on. So for example, you can change these 3 commands:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout -b myFeature1Enhanced
```

to just 2 commands:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b myFeature1Enhanced origin/main

# or if you want to use the newer equivalent switch command:
git fetch
git switch -c myFeature1Enhanced origin/main
```

3. As a bonus of creating branches from the desired starting commit, perhaps you no longer need to maintain a local copy of `main`, so you can just delete it. Oftentimes it's quickly out of date anyway, and you can just fetch and use `origin/main` anytime you need it.
4. Note that `pull` is basically the same as issuing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, and since you just fetched recently, in step 5, the command `git pull origin myFeature1` will basically do the same thing as `git merge origin/myFeature1`, but the explicit merge will be slightly faster since it won't fetch and wait to receive no changes first.
5. In step 3, you pushed your changes. In repos that allow *feature* branches to be rebased, you could rebase `myFeature1` onto the latest `main` and then create your new feature branch from there:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/main myFeature1 # update myFeature1 with latest main
git switch -c myFeature1Enhanced # create the new branch
```

With this method `myFeature1Enhanced` will be in the same state as your method, but without the extra merge commit, and `myFeature1` will be updated with the latest `main` as well, in case that is useful. Note this method requires force pushing `myFeature1` the next time you push it, which again is dependent on whether your repo allows force pushing personal feature branches. (I'd guess most repos allow this and only prevent it on shared branches such as `main` or similar.)

Comment: After executing my solution's commands of Step 5, I'm getting fatal error -

fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.


Any Suggestion ?